Couple applying faculty position to the same department/university
Let say a couple is applying the tenure-track positions in the same university. Question:

What would be the difference from normal faculty application?

a. Should they submit the application individually and mention this fact?
b. Should they contact the department head/search committee to discuss first?
c. Should they mention they only accept when both have offer, if they decided this?

For couple application, what would be the difference if applying the same or different department within a university?

Any other difference that should be considered? Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Your question will benefit from proofreading.

@Aruralreader I edited please let me know if anything in unclear.

Not quite a duplicate, but: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/161667/two-body-problem-tenure-track-and-phd (and many other questions that can be found by searching for "two body problem" or "spousal hire").

Is there only a single position they are competing for, or are there multiple?

Multiple positions. They are in separate job abs.

You should apply individually, but make sure that someone in the department (the chair, if you don't already know someone personally) knows that the two of you are married. There is no need to say that you will only accept offers if you both get one -- that is something that can be brought up once the department has decided that it wants to hire at least one of you, and it will be on the mind of the department members when thinking about your applications.
If you are applying to different departments, the same procedure applies: Apply individually, but let someone know that the two of you are married and both applying to positions at the university .

Yes, withhold conditions until it is time to make decisions.

Just married or the fact that the couple is also applying?

Let them know that your partner is also applying (and provide their name). It is clear to everyone that each of you will likely only accept an offer if you both get one. This is not an unusual situation.
